# Compiler error in the statement "a->friend = b;"

Tags: c++, class, syntax, c++20, keyword

unable to assign a shared pointer of a class to another shared pointer which is a member of the same class . expected unqualified-id before ‘friend’

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>

class foo {
    double num;
    int age;
    public :
        void info() {
            std::cout << num << " " << age << std::endl;
        }
        std::shared_ptr<foo> friend;
        foo() = delete;
        foo(double num_param, int age_param) 
            : num(num_param), age(age_param) {
                std::cout << num <<  " : constructed\n";  
            }  
        ~foo() {
            std::cout << num <<  " : destroyed\n" ;
        }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<foo> a{new foo(5.3, 56)};
    std::shared_ptr<foo> b{new foo(11.6, 89)};
    a->info();
    b->info();
    a->friend = b; //not working
    b->friend = a; //not working
    a->info();
    b->info();
    
    return 0;
}
```

why I am getting "expected unqualified-id before ‘friend’".
compiler g++-12

Comment: `friend` is a keyword in C++., as you can see from the above syntax highlight Use a valid name that is not a keyword. Also, the fact that you cannot tell `friend` is a keyword is a strong hint that you need a better IDE.

Comment: Use `std::make_shared<foo>(5.4,56);`? Also even if things would work, then you would end up with 2 instances having shared_ptr references to each other. This is a circular (liftime) dependency and should be avoided at all costs (by design). Because you will end up with instances that cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Weijun Zhou, commented "friend" is a keyword and it shouldn't be used as a identifier.
code worked after changing the shared pointer name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It’s not “shouldn’t” be used as an identifier, it is *can’t* be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

As `friend` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use it as an Identifier.

So, to solve the compilation error, you should change the member variable name from "friend" to "test" (any other non reserved keyword) to avoid the conflict with the reserved keyword.

- Change these lines in the code given

  ```
   a->friend = b; //not working
   b->friend = a; //not working
  ```
- to this

  ```
   a->test = b; //working
   b->test = a; //working
  ```